# Trying to solve "(2n+3)!/(2n+1)!" algebraically and my calculator gives different results

Tags: factorial

> $$\frac{(2n+3)!}{(2n+1)!}$$

I solved the above problem and I got $(2n+3)(2n+2)$, but I inputted it onto my TI92 plus. It gives me:
$\frac{(2n+3)!}{(2n+1)(2n)!}$
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you take a picture? I presume its a lack of correct parentheses issue.

Comment: The expression $(2n + 3)(2n + 2)$ is correct.

Comment: Your TI92's expression is also correct, it's just not as simplified as it could be.